# Public Key Unknown Encoding

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa, public-key

I have this public key:

```
MIGJAoGBAKv4OKlpY2oq9QZPMzAjbQfiqDqTnisSvdLP+mTswZJdbtk1J+4+qAySJuZjSQljzcUu0ANg+QG0VsvoU72zu5pErZKWubfe9HB/tq69bhP60qgP6/W2VebWlqUNGtsMedxuVaFBL3SoqU7e5RELIsuArCJJIgz86BQDX0x63VpXAgMBAAE=
```

I am trying to use it to decode this:

```
Zm/qR/FrkzawabBZYk7WfQJNMVZoZrwWTvfQwIhPMzAuqEO+y+sb/x9+TZwTbqmu45/GV4yhKv0bbDL8F6rif7RJap7iQUFQBDEIAraY42IGZ8pB6A0Q0RSnJWW+tLTLJg5cTrgZQ8sLoO+U03T6DE1wy73FU5h6XhXxZERo0tQ=
```

In which I know the unencrypted value is this:

```
2ABB43E83F7EC33D0D33F64BA5782E42
```

I have been trying several different things including Bouncy Castle (Java implementation) but I am unable to get the public key to work, mostly ending in invalid encoding errors.

This is my current implementation:

```
byte[] keyBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(PUB_KEY);
try {
        AlgorithmIdentifier rsaIdent = new AlgorithmIdentifier(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.rsaEncryption);
        SubjectPublicKeyInfo kInfo = new SubjectPublicKeyInfo(rsaIdent, keyBytes);
        ASN1Primitive primKey = kInfo.parsePublicKey();
        byte[] encoded = primKey.getEncoded();
        byte[] sessionBytes = Base64.decodeBase64("Zm/qR/FrkzawabBZYk7WfQJNMVZoZrwWTvfQwIhPMzAuqEO+y+sb/x9+TZwTbqmu45/GV4yhKv0bbDL8F6rif7RJap7iQUFQBDEIAraY42IGZ8pB6A0Q0RSnJWW+tLTLJg5cTrgZQ8sLoO+U03T6DE1wy73FU5h6XhXxZERo0tQ=");
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(encoded);
        KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance(spec.getFormat());
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, factory.generatePublic(spec));
        // ----- THIS IS WHERE IT BREAKS -----
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(sessionBytes);
        String tada = new String(decrypted, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
} catch (Exception e) { ... }
```

When I get to generate the public key from the factory I get

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown object in getInstance: org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Integer
```

I have tried several other things but all result in the same error above.

Is there something wrong with my public key?  What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Doing `.parsePublicKey` and (re)encoding the result just gives you back the same PKCS#1 key. If you instead use `kInfo.getEncoded()` you get the whole SPKI encoded and a KeyFactory-X509 can parse it. Because your value is really sort-of PKCS#1 signed not encrypted, JCE has a hack in Cipher-RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding (DECRYPT,RSAPublic) that gives the desired (but invalid) value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your key is PKCS#1 encoded. It's not a SubjectPublicKeyInfo structure required by Java. You can see how to decode it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33426378/589259).

Second, you cannot decrypt with a public key, you need a private key for that.

Comment: That fast enough for you, HuXu7?

Comment: Amazingly fast and very much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: The value here is actually PKCS#1-type1 (aka RSASSA-PKCS1v1_5) *signed* not encrypted, except with a highly suspect hash value (all ASCII hex digits) and without the AlgorithmIdentifier, probably by someone who believed the common lie that 'signing is encrypting with the private key'. JCE has a hack where `Cipher` for algorithm RSA can `ENCRYPT` with `RSAPrivateKey` and `DECRYPT` with `RSAPublicKey` and it actually does sign and recover instead.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I think that was because of the SSL signature format with both MD5 and SHA1. In that case only the PKCS#1 unpadding for signature verification was used, resulting in the hashes concatenated together.

Comment: The unpadded value is 32 bytes; MD5+SHA1 would be 36. It could be something like MD5+RIPEMDold, but the probability of all octets being hex digits is 2^-128.
I'd bet it's instead a 128-bit hash like MD5 converted to hex (32 chars) by someone who didn't know what they were doing, and the SEQ-AlgId-OCTSTR omitted for the same reason.

Comment: Ugh, I'll try and take a look at it when I have time for it (i.e. coming weekend or later) :)

Comment: "you cannot decrypt with a private key" - yes you can, doesn't matter which way round you do it; _should_ you? By convention, no, but it doesn't make it technically impossible.

Comment: There is a little more to it than that Ron. Small exponents, padding schemes and the fact that you suppose that everybody has access to a public key. Then there is side channel protection that is usually missing for public key operations and so on and so forth.

Comment: Yes sure, nobody said it was a good idea but again, it's not technically impossible is all I'm saying.